# Discord.py - Reminder command time issue

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I am trying to make a discord bot which has a reminder command. I would like the command to function as follows: `-remind 2h42m eat`. But right now it will only work if there is only one time included like `-remind 1h eat`. I'm not sure how to fix it can someone help ?

```
class reminder(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_ready(self):
        print('reminder.py is ready!')

    @commands.command()
    async def remind(self, ctx, time, *, task):
        def convert(time):
            pos = ['s', 'm', 'h', 'd']

            time_dict = {'s': 1, 'm': 60, 'h':3600, 'd':3600*24}

            unit = time[-1]

            if unit not in pos:
                return -1
            try:
                val = int(time[:-1])
            except:
                return -2

            return val * time_dict[unit]

        converted_time = convert(time)

        if converted_time == -1:
            await ctx.send('You did not enter a correct time format.')
            return

        if converted_time == -2:
            await ctx.send('You did not enter a correct time format.')
            return

        await ctx.send(f'Set a reminder in **{time}** from now.')

        await asyncio.sleep(converted_time)
        await ctx.send(f'{ctx.author.mention} Your reminder for `{task}` is ready. ')


async def setup(client):
    await client.add_cog(reminder(client))
```

I think i need to use

```
 asyncio.gather.
```

but since im a newbie im not sure how to implement it in my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is your parsing of the `time` string. It'll only work for one "unit".

We can use `regex` though to parse it a bit better I think.

```py
# with your imports
import re

def convert(time_str: str) -> int:
    time_dict = {'s': 1, 'm': 60, 'h':3600, 'd':3600*24}
    # this pattern looks for days, hours, minutes, seconds in the string, etc
    regex_pattern = r"^(?P<day>\d+d)?(?P<hour>\d+h)?(?P<minute>\d+m)?(?P<second>\d+s)?"
    matches = re.match(regex_pattern, time_str)
    total_time = 0
    for group in matches.groups():
        if not group:
            continue
        unit = group[-1]
        val = int(group[:-1])
        amount = val * time_dict[unit]
        total_time += amount
    return total_time
```

I would wrap the whole `convert` in a try/except to catch errors rather than in the function itself as well.

I tried a couple different strings and it worked fine.

[image]